# prevent data from add to db after Message Box

Tags: c#

I want after Message Box show

prevent data from insert to DB

```
int numberOfRecords = Convert.ToInt32(qotext.Text);
if (numberOfRecords == 9999)
{
    MessageBox.Show("try other value", "Error",
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Please include the entire function, not just your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need something like:

```
if (conditionToNotInsert) {
  MessageBox.Show(...);
} else {
  InsertStuffIntoDb();
}
```

The `else` block is only executed if the condition of the `if` is not true.

Comment: can you give me a simple example for "conditionToNotInsert"

Comment: @NAWAFWABS eg. `numberOfRecords == 9999`

Comment: if I want to replace "9999" by Column in database, can you help me for that by simple example

Comment: "Columns in database" makes no sense without a lot of context (and goes well beyond the question). Suggest you read the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and write a new question clearly explaining what you are trying to do, what you have (eg. what db access you are using; and what queries) and where you are stuck.